# Does Xubuntu support Ubuntu's Alt+F2 command?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, xubuntu, xfce, xkill

On normal Ubuntu Alt+F2 lets you enter a command that will execute as if ran in a terminal. This is most commonly used when your computer is not running properly and you need to `xkill`. Does Xubuntu support this by default? If not, how can it be enabled?

Comment: Did you try this yourself?

Comment: @vanadium I did. The cause of my lack of certainty is that it didn't work on my machine, but I've seen some signs online that it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it supports by default
press Alt+F2 and Application Finder will appear, then type xkill

If it didn't work you need to add the shortcut:
go to Settings > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts > Add
in the command box type: xfrun4
and then choose your shortcut.

Comment: So basically the equivalent feature is provided by **xfrun4** specifically, is that correct?

Comment: actually I never used alt+f2 in ubuntu . 
but with xfrun4 you can run some commands.

Comment: I can take this information as a "yes" to my question :) Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Opening the Application Finder manually and typing in `xkill` doesn't open xkill for me.

Comment: There is two application finder in xfce, one with icons and another one without! check this photo: https://ibb.co/RTRF2Rv